# Por que não consigo imprimir de acordo com o estado?

Tags: java

```
public class Lampada {

private boolean ligada = true;

/*
 * Métodos acessores e modificadores
 */
public void setLigada(boolean alteraEstado) {
    this.ligada = alteraEstado;
}

public boolean isLigada() {
    return ligada;
}
```

}

====

**Não funciona, fiz desse outro jeito**

```
   public class Main {

public static void main (String [] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Comando 'ligar' ou 'desligar' lampada.");

    String comando = sc.nextLine();
    Lampada lampada = new Lampada();

    switch (comando) {

        case "ligar":
            lampada.setLigada(true);
            System.out.println("Lampada ligada.");
            break;

        case "desligar":
            lampada.setLigada(false);
            System.out.println("Lampada desligada.");
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aonde você está executando os arquivos? (como por exemplo, em uma IDE ou no prompt de comando), e na nova versão, você modificou a classe `Lampada`?

Comment: Talvez você tenha esquecido de recompilar os arquivos, eu testei o código e deu certo

Comment: Eu usei a classe `Lampada` que o @Maniero♦ sugeriu e a classe `Main` da sua edição

Comment: Uma das possibilidades é que o Java está de alguma forma se confundindo na hora de realizar as operações, tente excluir os arquivos da `Lampada` e do `Main` e tente novamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente:

`Main`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main (String [] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Comando 'ligar' ou 'desligar' lampada.");

    String comando = sc.nextLine();
    Lampada lampada = new Lampada();

    switch (comando) {
      case "ligar":
        lampada.setLigada(true);
        System.out.println("Lampada ligada.");
        break;
      case "desligar":
        lampada.setLigada(false);
        System.out.println("Lampada desligada.");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

`Lampada`:

```
class Lampada {
    private boolean ligada = true;
    public void setLigada(boolean alteraEstado) {
        this.ligada = alteraEstado;
    }
    public boolean isLigada() {
        return ligada;
    }
}
```

Log:
(Tive problemas com as imagens então vou colocar em texto mesmo)

Ligar:

```
Comando 'ligar' ou 'desligar' lampada.
ligar
Lampada ligada.
```

Desligar:

```
Comando 'ligar' ou 'desligar' lampada.
desligar
Lampada desligada.
```

Comment: Estranho, quando eu testei deu certo mesmo desligada

Comment: Claro, aguarde um tempo, vou mostrar prints

Comment: Tente adicionar um `default` no `switch-case` e ver o que acontece

Answer (score 2):

Tem alguns erros grosseiros no código, parece coisas aleatórias, quando resolve isto compila e funciona (acho, não sei o que deveria fazer). Tem um monte de coisa fora de lugar ou que não faz nada útil. Resolvi o problema, mas o código ainda não faz sentido algum, tentei melhorar sem fazer muitas presunções.

Tem coisas que não são erro, mas poderia ser melhor, por exemplo, o método `setLigada()` não faz sentido porque não deveria receber nada, deveria só ligar. Pra falar a verdade nem entendo porque está usando um `set` ali, é para ligar, ponto. E aí falta um método de para desligar. Esse é um dos erros de uso de *getters/setters* que sempre falo (dê uma pesquisada aqui).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Lampada {
    private boolean ligada = true;
    public void setLigada(boolean alteraEstado) {
        this.ligada = alteraEstado;
    }
    public boolean isLigada() {
        return ligada;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Comando 'ligar' ou 'desligar' lampada.");
        String comando = sc.nextLine();
        Lampada lampada = new Lampada();
        switch (comando) {
            case "ligar":
                lampada.setLigada(true);
                System.out.println("Lampada ligada.");
                break;
            case "desligar":
                lampada.setLigada(false);
                System.out.println("Lampada desligada.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/U3ivwO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Lampjava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/Lamp.java).

Comment: Provavelmente é por que tem a palavra `public`, dentro de métodos não colocamos modificadores de acesso